# Best solution for frequently access database in python for network application

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a network server written in python where client connect. It make new thread for every new client connection which lives while client is connected.
Now while client is connected, server keep doing db queries to get any possible update about client if any is made from admin portal.

I was opening db connection for every thread and letting it connected while client is connected but this is going to be a problem when 1-2 k Clients are connected and db is having 1-2 active connections.

I then changed it to close db connection and reconnect on demand but now with 2-3k clinets, server is making alot of connect and disconnect with db.

I tried MySQL db pool but problem is with 32 max pool size that is not a solution for me.

Anyone have any other idea or solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of having to many clients connected at the same time is not something that you can resolve only with code. When your app gets bigger you must have multiple instances of the same python server on different machine. Then you would use a **Load Balancer**. The **Load Balancer** is going to act like a forwarder. Basicly your client is going to connect to it and then the **Load Balancer** will forward data to an instance of your python servers.

If you want to learn more about load balancing, here are some links:

- https://iri-playbook.readthedocs.io/en/feat-docker/loadbalancer.html
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/

Now for the database, instead of creating a connection for every client, you could only use one database connection and share it between threads.

Comment: Thanks. Is mysqldb connection in python is thread safe? can I create multiple cursor at the same time on one mysql connection?

Comment: Which library are you using ?

Comment: I'm using  mysql.connector

Comment: On the second bullet point they say that a pool handles thread safety.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

Comment: pool is not an option. Max pool connection limit is 32 and when several thousands clients are connected, that limit get exhausted.

Comment: If you want there is sqlite3 which is thread safe but I don't know if you can use it to connect to ypur sql database. https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html